# How to put data from various .cshtm files into <div> of _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, layout, html

My _Layout.cshtml file has three "div" situated in one "div"(div id="content"). The full code is:

```
<body id="bckgrimg">           
   <div id="content">    
       <div id="leftcolumn">
           <ul >
             <li><a href="home/contactus">Contact us</a></li>
             <li><a href="home/aboutus">About us</a></li>                
           </ul> 
       </div>
   <div id="centercolumn">
       We'll put something useful here later
   </div>
   <div id="rightcolumn">
           <div id="gallery">
                <a href="../Slide1.JPG"><img src="..."/></a>
                <a href="../horse_B.jpg"><img src="..."/></a>
                <a href="../shore_B.jpg"><img src="..."/></a>         
           </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried to put data by writing "some text" in xxx.cshtml but I just add new  element on a web page as I have yet created  in _Layout.cshtml. I just would like to put exactly data from various .cshtml files into  of _Layout.cshtml.

Is it possible to put data from xxx.cshtml file into (Where it is wtiiten "We'll put something useful here later") of_Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Have you googled "mvc partial views"?

Comment: yeah, i have. It is not what I want.

Comment: Could you explain how what you want is different from a partial view? Are you trying to render the other view in an iFrame? Partial Views's purpose is to put the content of one view (a partial) into another view.

Comment: I wouldn't like to create a partial view for every view. I just would like to paste data from view to _layout tags.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was your _Layout view. So use `@RenderBody()` in `_Layout` and on each view, set it's layout to `_Layout`. Visual studio does this by default when you create a new view. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx). They enable you to insert content from any views into the layouts used by said views.